# Why is function in this program repeating? Pascal

Tags: pascal

Made a program for finding greatest common divisor, but for some reason the function is repeating.

```
var p,q:integer;
function nod(x,y: integer):integer;
begin
while y<>0 do nod(y,x mod y);
result:=x;
end;
begin
write('Enter two integers: ');
read(p,q);
write(nod(p,q));
end.
```

Comment: Your code uses the `y` variable to decide when to stop looping, but you never do anything that changes the value of `y` to make it stop.  So clearly, you need to fix your code so that the value of `y` changes every pass through the loop until the break condition (`y = 0`) can be met.

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the y variable, and the loop never ends.

Maybe:

```
var p,q:integer;
function nod(x,y: integer):integer;
begin
while y<>0 do 
  begin
    y:= nod(y,x mod y);
  end;
result:=x;
end;
begin
write('Enter two integers: ');
read(p,q);
write(nod(p,q));
end.
```